# Disable Ctrl+Q shortcut in Eclipse (prevent closing)

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse, hotkeys

In Eclipse, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> shortcut forces application closure. There are no warning messages AND if going to *Windows -> Preferences -> Keys*, there is nothing bound to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> and even if I bind something, it does not prevent closing.

Comment: I have the same exact problem on the latest Eclipse version (Kepler).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this trick and it worked for me, (Kepler Version)

Go to *Windows -> Preferences -> Keys*.

Search for `Close`, you will see two close shortcuts <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> & <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>
Select any one `Close` command & Now Click `Copy Command`, so you will see another `Close` Entry with no Key binding.

Click the newly created `Close` command (that will have no binding now, i.e. Blank in the Binding section). Now in the `Binding` section, assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> as your bind. Click `Apply`. Recheck in Eclipse whether <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> is closing your application / opened files. It will close.

Again now go to *Windows -> Preferences -> Keys*.

Search for `Close`, and Locate the binding which you have created `Close` -->   <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>. Click that and select the `Unbind Command`. Press `Apply`. Now <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> will do nothing.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It worked partially: everything like you said caused Eclipse to close, but when I unbinded every single entry found for "Close", I was then able to make `Ctrl+Q` "Close current tab". It is better than closing entire worspace and waiting for background workers to finish their cleanup :) Thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not related to key binding. To fix the issue you must remove <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> binding at the following file:

> YourWorkspaceRootFolder \ .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench\workbench.xmi

Remove the line that contains 'keySequence="CTRL+Q"', and Eclipse will never close again when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>.